# Enable using navigation system while moving on 2013 Toyota Sienna

Tags: toyota, sienna, navigation

I am looking for a code or some way of unlocking the Toyota navigation so that my passenger can type in destination info into it while the vehicle is moving. Can't enter anything into the navigation system when the van goes above 5mph. There is no law in Missouri to block this, so I would like it unlocked. Toyota says tough. I replied by saying that I guess my passenger would have to whip out my Garmin or paper map when I get into an unsafe area or can't pull over to the side of the road because there is none. The buyer of the vehicle should have to right to decide to use it or not, it's not Toyota's decision. Anyone have any answers? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you simply cannot unlock it. If you hunt around on forums, you'll see it was, and still is, a pretty big discussion topic. For example, [from this discussion about the 2011 model](http://www.toyotanation.com/forum/275-3rd-generation-2011/344856-2011-sienna-how-look-up-destinations-nav-while-driving.html) (product links removed):

> ***jsrober*** writes:
>
> Yes, that topic has been discussed to death. Just about everyone hated that "lockout" feature in Toyota's GPS system... however, Toyota swears by it. The "older" generation has a hidden "unlock" key to enable the GPS to work while driving but, of course, when Toyota updated their system they promptly rid of that hidden key. The only way to use it while driving now is to install an aftermarket device for about $300.

The user **Luu** posted a response from Toyota on the issue, here is a rather unsatisfying excerpt:

> We are sorry to hear of your dissatisfaction that many features of the navigation system in your Sienna are disabled while the vehicle is in motion. Our intention is to help avoid a situation in which the system may distract a driver and endanger lives. While we understand that it would be useful for front seat passengers to able to operate the navigation while the vehicle is in motion. However, if the front seat passenger was allowed to operate the system when the vehicle is in motion, there is no integrated safety system to prevent the driver from also being able to do so due to the current design of the passenger occupant detection system whereby a driver could place sufficient weight on the passenger seat to simulate the presence of a passenger.

Topics on other forums follow the same path.

In fact, this issue is apparently so annoying to consumers that there's even [an entire website dedicated to protesting it](http://www.toyotaoverride.com/).

That said, it seems folks have [discovered a means to bypass the system on certain newer models](http://www.toyotanation.com/forum/333-3rd-generation-2014/904858-mod-2015-highlander-navi-phone-lockout-bypass.html) (I also found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EegvJSc10d4), a hack to tricking the system into thinking you are parked). I cannot say if that works on older models.

With some patience, luck, and engineering finesse, you might be able to dig into your own system to try and discover exactly how speed / lockout information is communicated from the vehicle's sensors to the navigation unit and find a way to intercept it. However, if it is GPS based info and internal to the unit, that may not be possible.

It pretty much appears you're SOL unless you go with an after-market system, or the newer model hacks work for the older vehicles.